# Resync rename permission denied error while deploying python app on azure app service using Kudu

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment, kudu

I am deploying a Flask Application on Azure App Service using CI/CD integration with GitHub and Kudu.
After a new push to the repository, the app should be redeployed automatically as per the latest code. But the redeployment is failing with the following error logs:

```
...
Done running pip install.

Compressing existing 'antenv' folder...
Done in 31 sec(s).

Copying files to destination directory '/home/site/wwwroot'...
rsync: rename "/home/site/wwwroot/.logs.log.ghpy4f" -> "logs.log": Permission denied (13)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]
rsync: rename "/home/site/wwwroot/.logs.log.ghpy4f" -> "logs.log": Permission denied (13)\nrsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]\n/opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh oryx build /home/site/repository -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.7 -i /tmp/8d811ef91eff275 -p compress_virtualenv=tar-gz -p virtualenv_name=antenv --log-file /tmp/build-debug.log
```

Note: "logs.log" file is a file in my project's root directory in which I am storing the runtime exceptions/errors of my application.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm facing this issue with my startup.sh file. Did you find any solution ?

Comment: I realized that the the current instance of my app was still accessing the log file and hence it can't be changed